# Using MapServer with OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, mapserver

I have implemented MapServer in a Windows environment and I get a map from the following URL

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?
  mode=browse&
  template=openlayers&
  layers=all&
  map=C:/ms4w/apps/osm/basemaps/osm-google.map&
```

I need to mark multiple locations on a map, (using map icons) and need to update the map periodically, how do I achieve this?

I guess I have to add a new layer using OpenLayers but can't figure out where I need to make my changes.

Comment: It is a while since I've used UMN Mapserver, but the approach I took was to configure MapServer as a WMS server (ie. serving raster tiles) and then set OpenLayers to to use a WMS layer. This is also more efficient due to tiling.